# What am I to A? | Riddle

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, family

If teresa's daughter is my daughter's mother, what am I to teresa?

> 1. Grandmother
> 2. Mother
> 3. Granddaughter
> 4. I am teresa

Answer (score 3):

My answer is

> **None of those.**
>
>  Here is the family tree
>
> ```
>      (A)
>       |
>  (A's daughter) (me)
>       \         /
>      (my daughter)
> ```
>
> So A's daughter is my wife.
>  A is my mother-in-law and I am A's son-in-law.
>  So I am none of those relations to A, and I am not Teresa because I am a man.

Comment: Darn. I'm too late.

Comment: @Shinjo I'm trying to think if there is anything more of a puzzle to it, like constructing something from letters.

Comment: I was thinking that A' was like a mathematic derivative of A or something like that earlier, but I concluded that probably a typo.

Comment: I don't think that's right. See my answer.

Comment: @Duck the question was changed, but my answer stands.

Comment: Yes, I think while making the choices, there was either an error or it was meant to be none of the above.

Answer (score 1):

A has a daughter which is your daughter mother.

> ```
>      A
>
>      |
>
>  (A's daughter)      [you]
>
>        \               /
>         (your daughter)
> ```

won't you be:

> neither of the choice? But probably you're A's son in law?

Answer (score 0):

> Using the information given, I am teresa's daughter.
>
> We are given the information that we are in the middle generation, and out of the choices given, 2 is the only one that fits that criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's break the sentence down:

> "If Teresa's daughter is my daughter's mother, what am I to Teresa?"
> So daughter's mother means me. So we replace it. "If Teresa's daughter is me, what am I to Teresa?" So obviously, you are Teresa's daughter. That is not one of the question choices.

So the resulting answer is:

> None of the above.

Comment: That is not one of the options.

Comment: Neither is yours, none of the options work.